# openlayers show half wms layer with googlemap v3 api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openlayers, geoserver

Hi I need to show some shapefiles over a map, for that I use geoserver, openlayers and google maps V3, it works as far I do not use OpenLayers.Layer.Google, I can see  my shapefile.
This is my working code:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
"Google Hybrid",
{type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 30,srs:'EPSG:2077'}
// used to be {type: G_HYBRID_MAP, numZoomLevels: 20}
);
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Italy WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
        var regioni_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
"comuni",
"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
{
    layers: "prov2011_g" ,
    transparent: "true",
    format: "image/png",
    srs:'EPSG:2077',
},
{isBaseLayer: false}
);
map.addLayer(regioni_wms);
    //map.addLayer(ghyb);
map.addLayer(wms)
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

if I add the layer ghyb to the map, only half of my polygon is rendered and if  zoom in it disappears.I do not know if is a problem of mercator nor how to fix it.

Comment: thanks I changed to EPSG:900913 both the layers and set geoserver to force the srs to the declared, but does not work, a last think I noticed the native SRS is unknow for geoserver and it is not possible to change it

Answer (score 1):

Google layers are only projected in EPSG 900913. If you try to use anything else it is doubtful it will work. The good news is that Geoserver will reproject your wms service on the fly to EPSG 9000913. I would suggest chaniging to this projection in both your layers and seeing if that makes a difference.

One thing to note about this is if you are trying to print your layers they will not be to scale along the x axis. Also if you are using a measuring tool on your website you will need to ensure it can operate in a geodesic fassion.